# Styling parts of a split node in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles

Using the following code, I can currently produce the simple first multi-part node in the image below.  Is there a way to set the style for individual node parts such as a different background color as shown in the second node?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,rectangle,fill=blue!20,thick,scale=3,
              rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3] {
            \nodepart{one}      Foobar
            \nodepart{two}      Bazqux
            \nodepart{three}    hello world
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

All I really need right now is to change the fill color, but ideally I'd like to be able to customize more of it.  (x-posted from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30674359/839246))

Comment: Will this question help you? I think it's the solution to your question: [How can I customize different nodepart with different textures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119647/4778)

Comment: @Alenanno Yes!  [Ignasi's](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119715/79601) answer does precisely what I need it to, thanks!  Feel free to mark this as duplicate, I just hadn't come across that post in the couple hours of searching I had done.

Comment: Ok, don't worry :)